# How to group a list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, group-by

I have a list like

```
A= [(1,0,10),(1,10,20), (1,20,30), (2,5,25), (2,5,50), (2,50,100)]
```

I need to group it based on 1st member of each tuple in A, then the minimum and maximum value of each group. Output is like this

```
B = [(1,0,30),(2,5,100)]
```

Comment: Looks like you're looking for someone to write some code. You'll have much more luck in this regard if you show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: thanks  @mtitan8 for your comments.  Anyway I posted this means I could not find a way so far.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
def solve(lis):
    for k, g in groupby(lis, key=itemgetter(0)):
        lis = [y for x in g for y in x[1:]]
        yield (k, min(lis), max(lis))
...         
>>> list(solve(A))
[(1, 0, 30), (2, 5, 100)]
```